# Problem with Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common

Tags: .net, azure-blob-storage

I have been using WindowsAzure.Storage for some web apps.  In the .NET Framework 4.8 it is marked as deprecated. I tried to replace it with `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common` and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` which should have been sufficient for my purposes. Here is the code I have:

```cs
var account = GetCloudStorageAccount();
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobContainerName = containerName;
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
var blob = container.GetBlobReference(name);
blob.DownloadToStream(outputStream);
```

When I tried to run it with the new packages, I got

```
Exception Type: Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException
Exception Message: BeginWrite is not supported
Exception Source: Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you updated to a deprecated version. The `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common` and the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` package

> have been replaced by the following new Azure SDKs.
>
> The latest libraries to interact with the Azure Storage service are:
>
> - [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs)
> - [Azure.Storage.Queues](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Queues/)
> - [Azure.Storage.Files.Shares](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.Shares/)
>
> It is recommended that you move to the new package.

Migrate to `Azure.Storage.Blobs` to use the most recent package to interact with Blobs in Azure.

Comment: These replacement packages require downgrading from .NET 4.5.1 to 2.0. Is this really the only option?

Comment: @Ben These packages are .NET Standard 2.0 compliant, which means they can be used in .NET Framework 4.6.1, .NET Core 2.0 _and up_. So no downgrading needed. For more information, see [.NET Standard - .NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).

Comment: @rikcvbosch - my app is 4.5.1 and I get the error saying something like "no references found that target .NET 4.5.1. So I take it upgrading the app to 4.6.1 will do the trick?

Comment: @Ben yep, the upgrade should do the trick.